# How to convert IntPtr to InteropService.SafeHandle?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

From the answer provided here [Can I choose a custom image for C# Windows Application Drag Drop functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078211/can-i-choose-a-custom-image-for-c-sharp-windows-application-drag-drop-functions), why does the following line:

```
return new Cursor(CreateIconIndirect(ref tmp));
```

cause the compiler to emit this error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Input.Cursor.Cursor(string)' has some invalid arguments
>       Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IntPtr' to 'System.Runtime.InteropService.SafeHandle'

and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: That code can only work in a Winforms project.  You don't want to use it anyway, it has a nasty handle leak that will crash your program after a while.

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue here is that you are trying to use a code example meant for the Winforms API when you are actually using the WPF API. The `Cursor` class used in that code is `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor`, while the class you're using is actually `System.Windows.Input.Cursor`. They are completely different, including having completely different constructors.

The Winforms version will accept an `IntPtr` value, representing a handle to a native Windows cursor object. But the WPF class accepts only some existing .cur or .ani data, either via a `Stream` (the data itself) or a `string` instance (the name of a file…this can be a `pack:` scheme path, so you can use embedded resources if you like).

If you want to create a cursor from an image on the fly in WPF, you can either:

1. Use the Winforms example but instead of trying to pass the cursor handle to the `Cursor` constructor, use additional native functions via interop to retrieve the cursor data, write it to an array, and then wrap the array in a `MemoryStream` that you can pass to the WPF `Cursor` constructor. Or,
2. Use one of the WPF-specific solutions for creating a `Cursor` object from existing image data. For example, [Custom cursor in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46805) (I particularly like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24246960)…there are several good ones there, though they all involve using GDI+ via the `System.Drawing` namespace at some point), or [Rotating Cursor According to Rotated TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2835502) (again, uses GDI+).