# During drag drop, how to show a popup with text(or a cursor with text) that follows the mouse cursor in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to show a popup to the user when he is dragging files or items onto my control. The popup basically informs him why dragging is disabled by giving him a message. I would like the popup to follow the mouse cursor whilst he is still in dragging mode.

OR is there a way to change the mouse cursor while dragging and displaying a text alongside the cursor? 
If there are any other designs that you guys can suggest.. that would be nice too.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You might finde some suggestions on how to change the cursor here: [Custom cursor in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805/custom-cursor-in-wpf)

One suggestion is to draw your popup on a canvas and move it as the cursor moves.