# I want to change my cursor in wpf to an custom .cur file?

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor, mouse

I want to change my mouse pointer to an custom cursor in my application.

So when my application starts, i want the custom cursor, and when it stops i want it gone.

How to do this in c# behind the code in wpf?

Comment: The accepted answer even just links to the other question. Clearly a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have the cursor changed for the whole operating system environment, only the WPF window.

Follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805/custom-cursor-in-wpf) on how to set a custom cursor

Answer (score 2):

You Can implement it this way. Simple steps. Just have to give the .cur image path and bind it with Cursor.

```
<Window>
   <Window.Resources>
       <Cursor x:Key="OpenHandCursor">C:\Users\Images\InvalidS.cur\ </Cursor>
   </Window.Resources>
</Window>

<StackPanel oriential="Horizontal" Cursor="{StaticResource OpenHandCursor}"> ............................... </StackPanel>
```

Thank You

Comment: Please be more detailed.