# How do I change to a black Windows arrow cursor?

Tags: wpf, windows, user-interface, cursor

I've noticed that both Visual studio and blend change from the standard Windows white cursor to a black cursor when you hover over certain areas.  I looked in the Cursors enumeration and couldn't find an equivalent black cursor.  Is this a special cursor included in Visual Studio or is this part of Windows?  Where do I find this cursor resource?  Thanks.

Comment: Windows does have a standard black arrow cursor.  It's IDC_ARROW in the "Windows Black" pointer scheme, so you wouldn't see it unless you'd changed the scheme.  The cursor file lives at `\Windows\Cursors\arrow_r.cur`, so you could load it as a custom cursor.  I don't know if this is the same as the black arrow used by Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, it's the black cursor.  Is there an API call to change the scheme?  I am using C#, but I can always do a PInvoke if necessary.  BTW, try answering the question with the answer, so you can get some points. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows does have a standard black arrow cursor. It's `IDC_ARROW` in the "Windows Black" pointer scheme, so you wouldn't see it unless you'd changed the scheme.  Note that the pointer scheme is strictly a user preference.  Applications should not change it, ever.

The cursor file lives at `\Windows\Cursors\arrow_r.cur`.  The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805/custom-cursor-in-wpf) describe several techniques for setting a custom cursor in WPF.