# How to change color of a cursor hovering above UserControl (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

So basically the title says it all - I have a `UserControl` and when the user moves cursor over it I want to change it's color. If my control would be a `TextBox` then it would be easy, since it has a `CaretBrush` property. An example of such behavior would be VisualStudio design area - cursor color varies depending on chosen theme.

Comment: I think the when hovering is the easy part of the question. 
the question is how do you customize or create your own courser. 
A good place to start : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805/custom-cursor-in-wpf

Comment: So you're saying that I would have to create my own cursor? Aw, damn...

Comment: I'm not sure. but it kinda seems like it..  i hope there's an easier way..

Comment: I don't get it - why this question was downvoted and somebody wants it to be closed? It's entirely valid question...