# How to override Mouse cursor with a custom image cursor?

Tags: wpf, mouse

I want to override Mouse cursor on a button's `MouseLeftButtonDown` event.
Overriding with standard cursor has no problem and it is something like as below:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
```

Now, I want to override with some custom cursor. So, I tried doing as below:

I have added the `MyCursor.cur` to my project and tried overriding the cursor as below.

```
var uriSource = new Uri("../MyCursor.cur", UriKind.Relative);
Mouse.OverrideCursor = new Cursor(uriSource.ToString());//Exception is thrown saying Absolute path is not valid.
```

I hope I was doing something wrong in getting the path of ".cur".

Could anyone please let me know the right way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer here [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805/custom-cursor-in-wpf). Unfortunately the link within the answer seems to be dead, however there are still some relevant bits within the answer itself, e.g.:

> If you need to load the cursor from a relative path or from a resource packed with your assembly, you will need to get a stream from the file and pass it in to the Cursor(Stream cursorStream) constructor. Annoying but true.